# NLog: Where is NLog Config?

Tags: c#, nlog

I coded this:

```
private static readonly ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

public MyClass()
{
    Console.Write("lol");
    Logger.Debug("Debug test...");
    Logger.Error("Debug test...");
    Logger.Fatal("Debug test...");
    Logger.Info("Debug test...");
    Logger.Trace("Debug test...");
    Logger.Warn("Debug test...");
}
```

And nothing displays.. so I was told to go and add `<targets>` to the config file, thing is.. where is the config file? Nothing on google, the documentation, or anything like that helps me...

Comment: Add NLog using Nuget. It will add the config file to your project.

Comment: I have, no NLog.config file from what I can see, only a .DLL in references

Comment: You have to create your own nlog.config with Nuget 3+

Answer (score 6):

From [NLog](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file) Wiki:

> The following locations will be searched when executing a stand-alone *.exe application:
>
> - standard application configuration file (usually applicationname.exe.config)
> - applicationname.exe.nlog in application’s directory
> - NLog.config in application’s directory
> - NLog.dll.nlog in a directory where NLog.dll is located (only if NLog isn't installed in the GAC)

So, the easiest would be to add a `NLog.config` file in the application’s directory

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can define the config programmatically in C# as explained in the blog docs here:
https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configure-from-code

Answer (score 2):

Sample Nlog.config File for your reference:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwConfigExceptions="true">

    <targets>
        <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="file.txt" />
        <target name="logconsole" xsi:type="Console" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logconsole" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial